# How to return response of one lambda function to another using SNS

Tags: amazon-s3, aws-lambda, amazon-sns

I have a lambda function A which is written in nodejs and writes some files to S3 . Another lambda function B is having S3 trigger (which is dependent on lambda A S3 path).I need to send back some message to lambda A using SNS . What is the ideal way to achieve this approach in aws ?

Answer (score 1):

One possible approach would be to have something like this -

X ----> S3 ----> (S3 Event on SNS)SNS-Trigger-To-Lambda -----> (Invocation-Type: Event)Lambda-A -----> (standard REST)Lambda-B

Here X is the producer service that publishes events to S3 bucket. Consequently, S3 will send notification to an SNS Topic.
This way, you get the data regulated before the Lambda-A. And Lambda-A to Lambda-B becomes a synchronous invocation.

Comment: @Rashmi if the answer solves your problem, please accept the answer.